# jQuery two step login script

Tags: jquery

I have a form field where a user adds an email, this passes information via the URL and inserts the email into a client login page.

**HTML**

```
<form method="GET" action="client_login" _lpchecked="1">
    <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email" name="email">
    <button type="submit" id="submit">LOGIN</button>
</form>
```

Output example: https://websitename.com/client_login?email=name.lastname%40email.com

**THE SCRIPT**

This goes on the login page to capture the URL information.

```
function getQueryString() {
 var result = {}, queryString = location.search.substring(1),
 re = /([^&=]+)=([^&]*)/g, m;
 while (m = re.exec(queryString)) {
 result[decodeURIComponent(m[1])] = decodeURIComponent(m[2]);
 }
 return result;
}
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
 document.getElementById('user').value = getQueryString()['email'];
});
```

The script works great, that's not the issue, the issue is when you go directly to the client login page without passing any URL information I get "undefined" in the username field, any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: here is some help: try asking a better question

Comment: what exactly is your problem?why don't you test if the email is in the url?

Comment: I tried to be detailed and give back story on how my setup works, clearly more confusing to some then others,,,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
value = getQueryString()['email'];
document.getElementById('user').value = value ? value : '';
```

Replace this with your above line.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the value is null, and give it a different value if so. If the ?email= query string isn't available, it's going to insert Undefined.